Sort a numpy array by row according to the first value of each row, then the second value
I'm trying to sort an array by row according to the first value of each row, then the second value if the first ones are the same and so on...
For instance, this array
l_2d = np.array([[20, 3, 100], [1, 200, 30], [300, 10, 2], [20, 8, 234]])
l_2d
array([[ 20,   3, 100],
       [  1, 200,  30],
       [300,  10,   2],
       [ 20,   8, 234]])

should be sorted this way :
array([[  1, 200,  30],
       [ 20,   3, 100], 
       [ 20,   8, 234],  
       [300,  10,   2]])

As my matrix is very large, I'd like to avoid having to use a for loop.
After looking to different numpy functions like argsort or sort, I wasn't able to find the one that would do the job.
Is there a build-in function to do so?

You're looking for numpy.lexsort
